# R Bigquery Error : attempt to apply non-function API Data Failed to Parse

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I am trying to do a simple Query with R and BigQueryR

https://github.com/cloudyr/bigQueryR:

I am not sure what is wrong but I keep getting an error (this might just be my lack of knowledge with R).

It is returning a list of projects and data sets correctly so I know it is connected.

I followed the guides on querying:

https://rdrr.io/cran/bigQueryR/man/bqr_query.html

```
bqr_query(projectId, datasetId, query, maxResults = 1000)
```

This is the command I put in:

```
result <- bqr_query("bigqyerytestproject2", "TestDataSet1", "SELECT * FROM TestTable3", maxResults = 1000)
```

and I get the error:

```
Error : attempt to apply non-function
Warning message:
In q(the_body = body, path_arguments = list(projects = projectId)) :
  API Data failed to parse.  Returning parsed from JSON content.
                    Use this to test against your data_parse_function.
```

But then I checked BigQuery and the query is going through successfully:

I am just connecting a small amount before I move a large data set but the results are:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Season",
    "Date": "2010-06-30",
    "ID": "1"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Test",
    "Date": "2010-06-30",
    "ID": "2"
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your app's needs, you might consider using [bigrquery](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery) instead of bigQueryR. The difference is explained [here](http://code.markedmondson.me/bigQueryR/).

Beyond that, I'd suggest filing an issue with the developer of the bigQueryR library.

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe how I got past that same error in case it's helpful, though I think it might be a slightly different problem as mine was caused by a permissions error with Google Sheets.

To create the error, I can:

1. Create a Google Sheets spreadsheet
2. Use the spreadsheet as a source of a BigQuery table
3. Query the BigQuery table using bqr_query()
4. At this point an error will pop up due to insufficient permissions
5. After seeing the error I grant permission to edit the Google Sheet to my app
6. The error "Error : attempt to apply non-function" appears and I can't get rid of it.

If I don't query the table until after granting permission to my app, the error doesn't appear in the first place.  So I just had to recreate the Google Sheet and BigQuery table.

Hope this helps!